# SortedList cannot find some keys that do exist (Unity3d, C#)

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, procedural-generation, voxel

this is my first question because it's the first one in years that I haven't been able to find a pre-existing answer for.

I am creating procedurally generated meshes in Unity. They need to be built out of an array of vector3s(3 dimensional points), and an array of ints representing indices of the vector3s.

I am using a SortedList to track vertices, so that I can use them multiple times in a single mesh and apply deformations to them. This is the best option because it tracks indices and a custom key type(3 dimensional position in this case)

```
public SortedList<Pos, Vector3> verts = new SortedList<Pos, Vector3>();
public List<int> tris = new List<int>();
```

For some reason, when I run

```
trisOut[0] = verts.IndexOfKey(vertPos[0, 1, 1]);
```

It functions normally a majority of the time, but occasionally returns "-1" meaning that it cannot find a matching position to the one in my little rendering field. This is the pair of triangles it finds:

```
Tri-Set 996 999 -1 996 -1 989
```

Which is really strange, considering it is looking for

```
(13, 7, 16) (14, 7, 16) (14, 7, 15) (13, 7, 16) (14, 7, 15) (13, 7, 15)
```

I checked this with my logs, and `(14, 7, 15)` exists and has index 996, leading me to check the others. This is the final rendered face in the chunk:

```
(15, 7, 16) (16, 7, 16) (16, 7, 15) (15, 7, 16) (16, 7, 15) (15, 7, 15)
```

Here are the vertices it is actually finding when it looks for those:

```
(16, 7, 16) (16, 7, 15) (16, 7, 15) (16, 7, 17) (16, 7, 15) (16, 6, 2)
```

WHAT? that doesn't make any sense, considering these are printouts from a method inside of each struct! It should be able to match itself to the other keys(CompareTo) because it is only checking for matches, not whether or not it is greater or less than. "==" is a pretty simple operation...

```
public int CompareTo(Pos c)
{

    if (this.x == c.x && this.y == c.y && this.z == c.z)
        return 0;
    else if (this.x + this.y + this.z < c.x + c.y + c.z)
        return -1;
    else
        return 1;
}
```

this is called in 6 cases, with 6 operations each which look like this

```
case Direction.up:
                trisOut[0] = verts.IndexOfKey(vertPos[0, 1, 1]);//UNW
                trisOut[1] = verts.IndexOfKey(vertPos[1, 1, 1]);//UNE
                trisOut[2] = verts.IndexOfKey(vertPos[1, 1, 0]);//USE

                trisOut[3] = verts.IndexOfKey(vertPos[0, 1, 1]);//UNW
                trisOut[4] = verts.IndexOfKey(vertPos[1, 1, 0]);//USE
                trisOut[5] = verts.IndexOfKey(vertPos[0, 1, 0]);//USW   
                Debug.Log("Verts: " + verts.Count);
                Debug.Log("looking for " + vertPos[0, 1, 1] + " " + vertPos[1, 1, 1] + " " + vertPos[1, 1, 0] + " " + vertPos[0, 1, 1] + " " + vertPos[1, 1, 0] + " " + vertPos[0, 1, 0]);
                Debug.Log("Tri-Set " + trisOut[0] + " " + trisOut[1] + " " + trisOut[2] + " " + trisOut[3]+ " " + trisOut[4] + " " + trisOut[5]);
                break;
```

Another place the issue may be occurring is where I create a mini-chunk around the block to figure out the positions of all 8 surrounding vertices(which populate the array used above).

```
    Pos[,,] vertPos = new Pos[2, 2, 2];
    int[] trisOut = new int[6];
    Debug.Log("Pos" + pos);
    for (int x = 0; x < vertPos.GetLength(0); x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < vertPos.GetLength(1); y++)
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < vertPos.GetLength(2); z++)
            {

                vertPos[x, y, z] = pos;
                vertPos[x, y, z].x += x;
                vertPos[x, y, z].y += y;
                vertPos[x, y, z].z += z;
                Debug.Log("VertPos" + vertPos[x, y, z].x + " " + vertPos[x, y, z].y + " " + vertPos[x, y, z].z);
            }
        }
    }
```

Which is followed by code that selects four vertices out of those eight to form a face. My vertex generating code works fine, I have logs showing each one at it's correct location, but the vertexes found by my triangle generating algorithm seem to be offset in some really weird way.

Comment: Hard to say how you generate the points, but if you have floating point coordinates and do any math at all to get the coordinates than failure to compare for exact values is expected.

Comment: Yeah I know that, that is why I am storing each one with Pos as the key(uncalculated coordinate), and a final location(Vector3) as the value. That way I can search for it based on it's original location while still being able to modify where it is rendered.

EDIT: Pos is made up of integers for X, Y, and Z, which are never modified once stored in my SortedList, only the Vector3 in the SortedList is changed from the original X, Y, and Z at the coordinates of its Pos

Comment: You need to post [MCVE] so someone can help you. Guessing what is wrong without actual code is not on-topic on SO.